# Bootstrap dropdown menu submenu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap menu doesn't show the submenu dropdown. Here's the code. I'm using Bootstrap 3. The "dropdown-submenu" class I believe should be the one to show the arrow and on click show the submenu ul.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Category
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/arts">Arts</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/artist-profiles">Artist Profiles</a>
   </li>
       </ul>
  </li>
   <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/buzz-quiz">Buzz Quiz</a>
    </li>
   <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/coast">Coast</a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/crime-security">Crime/Security</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/rape-resources">Rape Resources</a>
   </li>
    <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/security-overview">Security Overview</a>
  </li>
       </ul>
 </li>
   <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/environment">Environment</a>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/fashion">Fashion</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li >
        <a href="/lifestyle/category/about-fafa">About FAFA</a>
   </li>
   <li >
      <a href="/lifestyle/category/designers">Designers</a>
   </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? If it is, it's missing toggle button: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

Comment: I've included the whole div

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.3.5 (*current*) documentation and Bootstrap 3.3.5 CSS file do not contain a definition for `dropdown-submenu` class. 
It means that this class is redundant and does not affect the code at all (of course, if you haven't described it in your own CSS).
Here is the [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2fksbbd/) which works how it should work.

I have found a definition of `dropdown-submenu` in [Bootstrap 2.3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html) but it looks like it is depricated now.
Here is the [working JS Fiddle Demo with submenus](http://jsfiddle.net/w2fksbbd/1/) with Bootstrap 2.3.2.

However, I **highly** recommend not to use an outdated library because of a single feature.